# Looking to byepass a security for a webpage using AngularJS and Springboot

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, spring-security

Using AngularJS  stateProvider with Springboot. So when user hits any page URL it comes to AngularJS controller firstly and then to Spring Controller which renders the page.

```
$stateProvider
        .state('registration', {
            url: '/registration',
            templateUrl: 'registration',
            controller: 'registrationController',
            controllerAs: 'registrationController',
             });
```

Inside Spring controller method-

```
@RequestMapping("/registration")
String VoterRegistrationPageHandler(ModelMap modal) {                
        return "registrationpage";
}
```

Also for the http security, security configurations are used for all the endpoints for ex. An endpoint for /api/user/** should be accessed by only a user with role as user. Adding to that I have provided the custome form for the authentication like below.

```
@Override
        protectedvoidconfigure(HttpSecurity http) throwsException {
                http.authorizeRequests()                        
                .antMatchers("/api/user/**").hasAnyRole("Admin","User")
                .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("userName").passwordParameter("password")
                .and().csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
                
        }
```

Now I want that one of the template page which should not need the authentication by the user and hence I want to bye-pass the security configuration for that page so user should not be asked to login and directly the page should be displayed. Tried to add that in http security but did not work. Any suggestions please.

Adding the code how i added this in Security Configuration-

```
@Override
    protectedvoidconfigure(HttpSecurity http) throwsException {
            http.authorizeRequests()  
            .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll() ///newly added
            .antMatchers("/api/user/**").hasAnyRole("Admin","User")
            .and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("userName").passwordParameter("password")
            .and().csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
            
    }
```

Comment: @dur thanks for the comment. please check the code. Added in the question.

Comment: Did you get the login form? Could you login with username and password? Are you sure your configuration is used at all?

Comment: Yes, I am getting login form for any of the direct links i am providing and after login i am able to go to that page. Also to add, all APIs if user not authorized, i get whole login form template as response.

Comment: Maybe it is a CORS problem. Are the domains and ports of your frontend and your backend the same?

Comment: Although i am not sure if i get above question related to ports of front end and back end and all but yes, its running at localhost:8080 and obviously all requests are generating from inside the application itself.